# Python - Renaming all files in a directory using a loop

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a folder with images that are currently named with timestamps. I want to rename all the images in the directory so they are named 'captured(x).jpg' where x is the image number in the directory.

I have been trying to implement different suggestions as advised on this website and other with no luck. Here is my code:

```
path = '/home/pi/images/'
i = 0
for filename in os.listdir(path):
  os.rename(filename, 'captured'+str(i)+'.jpg'
  i = i +1
```

I keep getting an error saying "No such file or directory" for the os.rename line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The results returned from `os.listdir()` does not include the path.

```
path = '/home/pi/images/'
i = 0
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path,filename), os.path.join(path,'captured'+str(i)+'.jpg'))
    i = i +1
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `rename()` takes absolute paths, You are giving it only the file names thus it can't locate the files.

Add the folder's directory in front of the filename to get the absolute path

```
path = 'G:/ftest'

i = 0
for filename in os.listdir(path):
  os.rename(path+'/'+filename, path+'/captured'+str(i)+'.jpg')
  i = i +1
```

Comment: why I got PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process? I thought I was renaming files instend of opening it

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

- Use glob. This gives you more fine grained control over filenames and dirs to iterate over.
- Use enumerate instead of manual counting the iterations

Example:

```
import glob
import os

path = '/home/pi/images/'
for i, filename in enumerate(glob.glob(path + '*.jpg')):
    os.rename(filename, os.path.join(path, 'captured' + str(i) + '.jpg'))
```

Answer (score 1):

## This will  work

```
import glob2
import os


def rename(f_path, new_name):
    filelist = glob2.glob(f_path + "*.ma")
    count = 0
    for file in filelist:
        print("File Count : ", count)
        filename = os.path.split(file)
        print(filename)
        new_filename = f_path + new_name + str(count + 1) + ".ma"
        os.rename(f_path+filename[1], new_filename)
        print(new_filename)
        count = count + 1
```

## the function takes two arguments your filepath to rename the file and your new name to the file